# Possible bug in FindRegionTransform

Tags: geometric-transform

Studying a new command `FindRegionTransform` of version 13.0.0 on Windows 10,
I try to reproduce an example from the documentation
[image]

, but obtain a different result

```
t = FindRegionTransform[Ball[{1, 1}], Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]]
```

> $$ \text{TransformationFunction}\left[\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -1.03232 & 0.497137 & -1.31904 \\
>  -0.537213 & -1.11553 & 1.65275 \\
>  0. & 0. & 1. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right]$$

and a different result in Wolfram Cloud

> $$ \text{TransformationFunction}\left[\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -0.0856246 & 1.14258 & -2.91117 \\
>  -1.23469 & -0.0925271 & 1.32722 \\
>  0. & 0. & 1. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right]$$

According to the documentation, `t[Ball[{1, 1}]]` should result in  `Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]`, i.e.

```
Region[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {3, 2}], PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True]
```

In fact,

```
Region[t[Ball[{1, 1}]], PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},Frame -> True]
```

[image]

One of such affine transforms, mapping `Ball[{1, 1}]` onto `Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]`,
can be found as follows

```
tr = TranslationTransform[{-1, -1}];h = ScalingTransform[{3, 2}];c = Composition[h, tr] // Simplify
```

> $$\text{TransformationFunction}\left[\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  3 & 0 & -3 \\
>  0 & 2 & -2 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right] $$

and this correctly works:`Region[c[Ball[{1, 1}]], PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},  Frame -> True]` shows `Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]`.

Is the result of `t = FindRegionTransform[Ball[{1, 1}], Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]]` a bug or I don't understand something?